# Scala and Java BigDecimal

Tags: java, math, scala, groovy, bigdecimal

I want to switch from Java to a scripting language for the Math based modules in my app. This is due to the readability, and functional limitations of mathy Java.

For e.g, in Java I have this:

```
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("1.1");
BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal("1.1");
BigDecimal z = x.multiply(y.exp(new BigDecimal("2"));
```

As you can see, without BigDecimal operator overloading, simple formulas get complicated real quick.

With doubles, this looks fine, but I need the precision.

I was hoping in Scala I could do this:

```
var x = 1.1;
var y = 0.1;
print(x + y);
```

And by default I would get decimal-like behaviour, alas Scala doesn't use decimal calculation by default.

Then I do this in Scala:

```
var x = BigDecimal(1.1);
var y = BigDecimal(0.1);
println(x + y);
```

And I still get an imprecise result.

Is there something I am not doing right in Scala?

Maybe I should use Groovy to maximise readability (it uses decimals by default)?

Comment: Are you *really* sure that using BigDecimal is the correct thing to do? What kind of calculations are you doing?

Comment: I can't verify the problem with BigDecimal in Scala. It's working as expected at least in 2.8.1

Comment: var x:BigDecimal = 11.0 should be exact, and x = x/10.0 should be happy.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I don't know Scala, but in Java `new BigDecimal(1.1)` initializes the `BigDecimal` with a `double` value and thus it is not *exactly* equal to 1.1. In Java you have to use `new BigDecimal("1.1")` instead. Maybe that will help in Scala as well.

Comment: Man, that's ugly. I guess if you care about decimal precision, using Groovy is by far the prettiest option. Its BigDecimal support isn't completely perfect yet, but far better than that of any other language.

Comment: @mcv What's happening is that in `BigDecimal(1.1)`, the expression 1.1 is parsed as a double, even before `BigDecimal` gets hold of its value. So you need `BigDecimal("1.1")` so that `BigDecimal` can be in charge of deciding what "1.1" means. This is a general problem (in any language's BigDecimal or equivalent) that AFAICT you can solve only with the language not automatically reading numeric literals as floating-point values (which I've always thought would save a lot of confusion), but I'm not aware of any language that does things this way.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR That's exactly what Groovy does. It has native BigDecimal support, and immediately interprets 1.1 as BigDecimal. That may be confusing for people used to native floats, but in business logic, it's usually what you actually want.

Answer (score 36):

Change your Scala code to this:

```
var x = BigDecimal("1.1");   // note the double quotes
var y = BigDecimal("0.1");
println(x + y);
```

and it will work just like it does in Java.

Comment: What's happening here? Why is `new` neither needed nor accepted?

Comment: Note that `BigDecimal("1.0")` without `new` is shorthand for `BigDecimal.apply("1.0")` - it calls the `apply` method of `object BigDecimal`, the companion object for `class BigDecimal`. The `apply` method is a factory method.

Comment: It doesn't work with `new` (at least not in Scala 2.10.0), because apparently `BigDecimal` doesn't have a public constructor that takes a `String`. That's probably a bug in Scala's version of `BigDecimal`. Note that it works if you do `new java.math.BigDecimal("1.0")`.

Comment: That's a different class. Where can I read about how the constructorless version works?

Comment: See the API docs of object [`scala.math.BigDecimal`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.BigDecimal$). The notation where `BigDecimal(...)` means the same as `BigDecimal.apply(...)` is Scala compiler magic.

Answer (score 13):

Scala is most definitely the same as Java in this respect.

As per Joachim's answer, writing `val x = BigDecimal(1.1)`

is equivalent to writing

```
val d : Double = 1.1
val x = BigDecimal(d)
```

The problem, of course, is that the Double `d` ALREADY has the rounding error, so you're initialising x with bad data.

Use the constructor that accepts a string instead, and all will be fine.

Given your example, you'd also be better off using `val`s instead of `var`s, and you can safely leave the semicolons off in Scala as well.

Comment: I can't verify the problem with BigDecimal in Scala. It's working as expected in 2.8.1

Comment: It is not equivalent. In the second case, you polute the namespace with a new variable, `d`.

Answer (score 7):

You can store values as Integer/String (without precision) internally and use `scale` (this is a transcript from Scala REPL):

```
scala> val Scale = 2
Scale: Int = 2

scala> val x = BigDecimal(110, Scale)
x: scala.math.BigDecimal = 1.10

scala> val y = BigDecimal(303, Scale)
y: scala.math.BigDecimal = 3.03

scala> (x+y, (x+y).scale)
res0: (scala.math.BigDecimal, Int) = (4.13,2)

scala> (x*2, (x*2).scale)
res1: (scala.math.BigDecimal, Int) = (2.20,2)
```

Or if you want to parse a string, you can control rounding:

```
scala> val z = BigDecimal("8.937").setScale(Scale, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.FLOOR)      
z: scala.math.BigDecimal = 8.93

scala> val z = BigDecimal("8.937").setScale(Scale, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.CEILING)
z: scala.math.BigDecimal = 8.94
```

Comment: Why you use `val x = new BigDecimal(new JBigD(JBigI.valueOf(110), Scale))` instead of `val x = BigDecimal(110, Scale)`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! I cannot recall if this method was available in Scala 2.7.x, but it is definitely the way to go in Scala 2.8. I'll fix the answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
scala> implicit def str2tbd(str: String) = new {
     |     def toBD = BigDecimal(str)
     | }
str2tbd: (str: String)java.lang.Object{def toBD: scala.math.BigDecimal}

scala> var x = "1.1".toBD
x: scala.math.BigDecimal = 1.1

scala> var y = "0.1".toBD
y: scala.math.BigDecimal = 0.1

scala> x + y
res0: scala.math.BigDecimal = 1.2

scala> implicit def str2bd(str: String) = BigDecimal(str)
str2bd: (str: String)scala.math.BigDecimal

scala> x + y + "1.2345566"
res1: scala.math.BigDecimal = 2.4345566

scala>
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, it simply demonstrates a different way to use the string constructor as already covered in different answers!

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old and answered, but another option, if you're open to different languages (as the OP seemed to be), would be to use Clojure.  Clojure has, IMO, some of the simplest syntax for `BigDecimal` math (note the trailing `M`s -- that indicates `BigDecimal`):

```
user=> (def x 1.1M)
#'user/x
user=> (def y 1.1M)
#'user/y
user=> (def z (* x (.pow y 2)))
#'user/z
user=> z
1.331M
user=> (type z)
java.math.BigDecimal
```

I like Clojure for math since it defaults to precision in many cases, e.g. its use of `Ratio`:

```
user=> (/ 60 14)
30/7
user=> (type (/ 60 14))
clojure.lang.Ratio
```

Comment: Definately better than the presented Scala version - if one likes polish notation.

Comment: @ziggystar Yep, you have to be willing to accept prefix/Polish notation, which might be seen as a big hurdle for many :)

Comment: Just wanted to point out that because Clojure is so malleable, it is possible for it to use infix notation with macros. [This post](http://data-sorcery.org/2010/05/14/infix-math/) shows an example in the Incanter library from some years ago.