# Where is the ceil function on scala.math.BigDecimal?

Tags: scala, bigdecimal

I can't find the ceil function in the places I've looked:

- https://duckduckgo.com/?q=scala+bigdecimal+ceil+function&t=ffab&ia=qa
- http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/BigDecimal.html

But I do find a [ceil method on Double and Float](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/BigDecimal$.html?search=ceil).

I know MathContext can be made to use the ceiling rounding mode, but I can't seem to make it work:

```
scala> BigDecimal("1.1").round(new MathContext(0, RoundingMode.UP))
res2: scala.math.BigDecimal = 1.1

scala> BigDecimal("1.8").round(new MathContext(0, RoundingMode.UP))
res3: scala.math.BigDecimal = 1.8

scala> BigDecimal("1.8").round(new MathContext(0, RoundingMode.CEILING))
res5: scala.math.BigDecimal = 1.8

scala> BigDecimal("1.8", new MathContext(0, RoundingMode.CEILING))
res6: scala.math.BigDecimal = 1.8

scala> res6.rounded
res8: scala.math.BigDecimal = 1.8
```

I expected the result of all the operations above to be `== BigDecimal(2)`.

I use a BigDecimal because these are money operations, hence I need exact values.

Comment: I found [Scala and Java BigDecimal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2698794/7355) which partially answers the question, by using the `setScale` method, and changing the scale to 0 and using the CEILING rounding mode. This would work for me, but my question still stands: why isn't there a simple `ceil` method available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the title question: there isn't. At least, not in the way that it exists for `Double` (and it doesn't *really* exist for `Double`, either, it's added implicitly).

You are specifying the precision of the `MathContext` as zero, which means you're saying you want unlimited precision--that is, no rounding will be done. If you want the true ceiling (rounding up to the nearest integer), then you don't want to use `BigDecimal#round` at all. The first parameter of the `MathContext` is *precision*, which is the number of significant digits you want to maintain. Rounding up a number like 1234567 to keep five significant digits would give you 1234600.

To find the ceiling of a number, you want to set the *scale*, which is the number of digits to maintain after the decimal point. In this case, you'd want a scale of zero.

```
import scala.math._, BigDecimal._

scala> BigDecimal("3134.1222").setScale(0, RoundingMode.CEILING)
res1: scala.math.BigDecimal = 3135

scala> BigDecimal("1.1").setScale(0, RoundingMode.CEILING)
res2: scala.math.BigDecimal = 2

scala> BigDecimal("1.8").setScale(0, RoundingMode.CEILING)
res3: scala.math.BigDecimal = 2
```

We can use the *enrich my library* pattern to add a `ceil` method to `BigDecimal` implicitly:

```
implicit class RichBigDecimal(bd: BigDecimal) {
  def ceil: BigDecimal = bd.setScale(0, RoundingMode.CEILING)
}

scala> BigDecimal("1.1").ceil
res6: scala.math.BigDecimal = 2
```